# docker login on version Version 17.09.1-ce-mac42 (21090) Channel: stable 3176a6af01 don't work

Tags: docker

I update docker version into 17.09.1-ce-mac42 (21090) Channel: stable 3176a6af01
docker login ce.site.io Version 17.09.1-ce-mac42 (21090) Channel: stable 3176a6af01 don't work

error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

do  which docker-credential-osxkeychain do check there is no other one in there ?
Alternatively, removing /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain and performing a reset to default in your docker for mac should do the trick, of getting rid of the one in /usr/local/bin